# Upgrate to Sonarqube 3.6 takes over 2 hours! Is it correct?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm just upgrading our Sonar installation, from v3.5.1 to 3.6, and the process has been running for over two hours. Last log file entry was "Convert 508818 violations to issues" as the process was starting.
Now, the sonar site /setup is still showing "Sonar database is currently upgrading".

Is it correct that the upgrade of 500.000 violations to issues takes so much time?
Why does the log file is not being updated?

Thanks in advance.
Andreas

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade from 3.5.1 to 3.6 can indeed last very long - but it will complete. You're facing this limitation: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4470

This is mainly linked to performance issues on JRuby side (DB migration scripts are usually written on Rails side). As you can read in the ticket, we decided to rewrite this migration script in full Java and to provide a SonarQube 3.6.1 fix version.